# filtering and removing items in a list using javascript

Tags: javascript

Im doing an assignment and don't need to do this, but would like to further my knowledge. I need to remove anything that says remove inside of this list.

```js
var sentence = ["REMOVE","Today","I'm","REMOVE","excited","to","learn","REMOVE","REMOVE","about","arrays"];
console.log("Original Sentence: " + sentence);

// Your code goes here

console.log("Final Sentence: " + sentence);
```

Here is how I did it, and instead of removing the "REMOVE", it shows every occurrence of remove. How do I get it to do the opposite of what it is currently doing.

```js
var sentence = ["REMOVE","Today","I'm","REMOVE","excited","to","learn","REMOVE","REMOVE","about","arrays"];
console.log("Original Sentence: " + sentence);
// Your code goes here
function filterItems(query) {
  return sentence.filter(function(el) {
      return el.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) > -1;
  })
}

var test = filterItems('re');

console.log("Fixed sentence" +test);
```

Comment: Invert the logic from your `filter` predicate.

Comment: Exactly what Andre said, do `< 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is backwards. [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) returns a new array containing elements that satisfy your predicate. Your predicate right now is "contains the word REMOVE".

You want the inverse (literally replace `> -1` with `< 0`):

```js
var sentence = ["REMOVE","Today","I'm","REMOVE","excited","to","learn","REMOVE","REMOVE","about","arrays"];
console.log("Original Sentence: " + sentence);
// Your code goes here
function filterItems(query) {
  return sentence.filter(function(el) {
      return el.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) < 0;
  })
}

var test = filterItems('re');

console.log("Fixed sentence" +test);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are filtering for items that contain your query, you just need to correct your filtering logic.

```js
var sentence = ["REMOVE","Today","I'm","REMOVE","excited","to","learn","REMOVE","REMOVE","about","arrays"];
console.log("Original Sentence: " + sentence);
// Your code goes here
function filterItems(query) {
  return sentence.filter(function(el) {
      return el.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) == -1;
  })
}

var test = filterItems('re');

console.log("Fixed sentence" +test);
```

Comment: @AciiD don't forget to accept this as the answer if it worked for you :)

Answer (score 0):

`.filter` creates a new array, and doesn't modify the existing, I would suggest using `.splice` instead...unless of course you plan to re-use the original `sentence` again and expect it to have it's original values

Something like this should work

```js
let sentence = ["REMOVE", "Today", "I'm", "REMOVE", "excited", "to", "learn", "REMOVE", "REMOVE", "about", "arrays"];
console.log("Original Sentence: " + sentence);

function filterItems(query) {
  for (var i = sentence.length - 1; i--;) {
    if (sentence[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) === 0) {
      sentence.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
  return sentence;
}

filterItems("re");
console.log("Fixed sentence: " + sentence);
```

Comment: I did something similar to this already and just wanted to try and figure out how to do it another way, Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Check the link about how to use filter method.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

```js
var sentence =["REMOVE","Today","I'm","REMOVE","excited","to","learn","REMOVE","REMOVE","about","arrays"];
console.log("Original Sentence: " + sentence);
var test = sentence.filter(word => word.toLowerCase() !== "remove");
console.log("Fixed sentence: " + test);
```